# after deploying the react app on render.com it says the site is dangerous when i click on deployed link

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, clone, netflix, render.com

[image: shows dangerous site]
I have created netflix clone using tmdb api and when we click on particular movie it shows a modal which plays trailer of movie .
the TMDB api key is stored in .env file

when i try to access the site using chrome it says that the site is deceptive , but when i use Brave browser it runs without any danger warning
how can i solve this
[this is the source code](https://github.com/sahilkhalidsolkar/netflix-clone)
[deployed react app link](https://netflix-clone-cnz8.onrender.com/)

[image: it should show directly the site without the danger warning on chrome]

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue!

Comment: The same issue, suddenly chrome marks it as dangerous